# Create N number of GCP compute instances using Rest api

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

How to create n number of instances in GCP using rest api.

 in AWS java SDK, there is a method **withMaxCount** where we specify number of ec2 instances.

Similarly is there anything for GCP compute.

Comment: The Google Cloud API does not have an equivalent to `withMaxCount`. The Google Cloud API is very easy to use. You can code a loop to create as many instances as your quota allows. The Google Cloud Console will show you the CLI command to create an instance. Use a shell script or you can add the command line option `--log-http` to can see the REST API to duplicate that command. Tip: look into using Terraform for deployments and skip using the API.

Comment: @JohnHanley, Thanks for the info

Comment: You are welcome. You have numerous tools, resources and options to build your infrastructure.

Comment: Do you want to create N GCE VM instances or GCE Managed Instance Group within REST API?

Comment: n GCE VM instances only

Comment: Thanks! As a workaround you can use a bash script with `gcloud` command where you can send some parameters like number of VM instances. Does it feet your use case?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza, No, As for my usecase, I need solution in java only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinstanceapi) in loop to create instances.
Example request will look something like this:

```
{
  "kind": "compute#instance",
  "name": "INSTANCE-NAME",
  "zone": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/zones/us-central1-a",
  "machineType": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/e2-medium",
  "displayDevice": {
    "enableDisplay": false
  },
  "metadata": {
    "kind": "compute#metadata",
    "items": []
  },
  "tags": {
    "items": []
  },
  "disks": [
    {
      "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
      "type": "PERSISTENT",
      "boot": true,
      "mode": "READ_WRITE",
      "autoDelete": true,
      "deviceName": "INSTANCE-NAME",
      "initializeParams": {
        "sourceImage": "projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20210122",
        "diskType": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-standard",
        "diskSizeGb": "10",
        "labels": {}
      },
      "diskEncryptionKey": {}
    }
  ],
  "canIpForward": false,
  "networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
      "subnetwork": "regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default",
      "accessConfigs": [
        {
          "kind": "compute#accessConfig",
          "name": "External NAT",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
          "networkTier": "PREMIUM"
        }
      ],
      "aliasIpRanges": []
    }
  ],
  "description": "",
  "labels": {},
  "scheduling": {
    "preemptible": false,
    "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
    "automaticRestart": true,
    "nodeAffinities": []
  },
  "deletionProtection": false,
  "reservationAffinity": {
    "consumeReservationType": "ANY_RESERVATION"
  },
  "serviceAccounts": [
    {
      "email": "111111111111-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "shieldedInstanceConfig": {
    "enableSecureBoot": false,
    "enableVtpm": true,
    "enableIntegrityMonitoring": true
  },
  "confidentialInstanceConfig": {
    "enableConfidentialCompute": false
  }
}
```

Replace it with your own project name and service account, and you can test it [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert).

Comment: hey the subnetwork under the networkInterafaces is wrong, it should be `regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default` the project name should not be mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The GCP REST API suports bulkInsert. Have a look at the following detailed description:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/multiple/create-in-bulk

Note that the above link is describing bulkInsert in regions. If you have a persistend disk (or etc) that is zonal, check out the bulkInsert for zones:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/bulkInsert

At the moment, I haven't found batchDelete for REST API, i need to loop over my instances. Although gcloud (CLI) does support it: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete